# How to specify the type/Head of the optional named arguments to a function?

Tags: argument-patterns, optional-arguments, arguments, api

I am trying to improve my own dsolver API. Currently it takes optional arguments.
Is it possible to specify that an optional argument should say be String only? Or List Only? Or Integer only? and so on.

Just like one does for normal arguments by using `_Head`

An example will make this more clear. Here is just an example, where the dsolve takes 2 optional arguments. The first is "ic" and the second is "hint". I want the value of the "hint" to be String.

Of course I can always check for this when I read the optional argument. But it will be better if Mathematica did that.

```
ClearAll[dsolve, y, x];
Options[dsolve] = {"ic" -> {}, "hint" -> ""};

dsolve[ode_Equal, y_[x_], x_, opts : OptionsPattern[{dsolve}]] := Module[{ODE, ic, hint},
  ic = OptionValue["ic"];
  hint = OptionValue["hint"];
  ODE = <|"ode" -> ode, "y" -> y, "x" -> x, "ic" -> ic, "hint" -> hint|>;
  ODE 
  ]
```

Now I can call it using

```
dsolve[y''[x] + y[x] == 1, y[x], x, "hint" -> "linear"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But I am also able to do this

```
dsolve[y''[x] + y[x] == 1, y[x], x, "hint" -> 3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To fix this, I change the function to the following

```
dsolve[ode_Equal, y_[x_], x_, opts : OptionsPattern[{dsolve}]] := Module[{ODE, ic, hint},
  ic = OptionValue["ic"];
  hint = OptionValue["hint"];
  If[Not[StringQ[hint]], Abort[]]; (*Added explicit check*)
  ODE = <|"ode" -> ode, "y" -> y, "x" -> x, "ic" -> ic, "hint" -> hint|>;
  ODE 
  ]
```

and now

```
dsolve[y''[x] + y[x] == 1, y[x], x, "hint" -> 3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Is there something like the following for making the optional arguments (I am making this up ofcourse, as this is wrong syntax, but just to give the idea of what I am looking for)

```
Options[dsolve] = {"ic"_List -> {}, "hint"_String -> ""};
```

This way I do not have to add explicit check, because the call  `dsolve[y''[x] + y[x] == 1, y[x], x, "hint" -> 3]` will not even match in the first place and will not go through.

Any suggestion if something like this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how to get this working when using `OptionsPattern` explicitly but at the cost of a bit more syntax when calling `OptionValue` and in the function declaration, I got something to work with a named optional argument of variable length `opts` (which stores the option(s)):

```
ClearAll[dsolve, y, x];
Options[dsolve] = {"ic" -> {}, "hint" -> ""};
OptionChecks[dsolve] = <|"ic" -> ListQ, "hint" -> StringQ|>;

dsolve[ode_Equal, y_[x_], x_, opts___] := Module[{ODE, ic, hint},
   ic = OptionValue[dsolve, {opts}, "ic"];
   hint = OptionValue[dsolve, {opts}, "hint"];
   ODE = <|"ode" -> ode, "y" -> y, "x" -> x, "ic" -> ic, "hint" -> hint|>;
   ODE
] /; CheckOptions[dsolve, opts]
```

where `CheckOptions` is defined as

```
ClearAll[CheckOptions]
CheckOptions[f_] := And@@(OptionChecks[f][#[[1]]][#[[2]]]&/@Options[f]/.Missing[_, _][_] -> Nothing)
CheckOptions[f_, o__] := And@@(OptionChecks[f][#[[1]]][#[[2]]]&/@{o}/.Missing[_, _][_] -> Nothing)
```

The association `OptionChecks[dsolve]` stores a set of checks for the arguments of `dsolve` (it is not necessary to include checks for all arguments). `dsolve` only tries to evaluate when called with the sequence of options `ops` if and only if `CheckOptions[dsolve, opts]` evaluates to `True`.

Calling `dsolve` with a valid set of options evaluates while an invalid set does not e.g.:

> [image: test1]

Changing the default options to invalid ones prevents evaluation with those options as intended and allows for evaluation only when specifying individual valid options e.g.:

> [image: test2]

I must admit that this solution with `CheckOptions` is more a workaround than a solution to the explicit question asked here since the present implementation requires a named argument for the options `opts` and the explicit check `/; CheckOptions[dsolve, opts]` in the function declaration. I would be very interested in a better solution closer to the one envisioned in the original question.